# Delete data using merge statement in Oracle

Tags: plsql

How to only delete data using merge using oracle...
I am using the below code:

```
Merge 
into 
target_table
using 
source_tablle 
on (...)
when matched 
then delete
```

But I am getting an error "missing Keyword" at last line

Answer (score 5):

Your `MERGE` at the end is missing the `UPDATE` clause.
Lets look at a sample `MERGE`

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
employee_id NUMBER(5),
first_name  VARCHAR2(20),
last_name   VARCHAR2(20),
dept_no     NUMBER(2),
salary      NUMBER(10));

INSERT INTO employee VALUES (1, 'Dan', 'Morgan', 10, 100000);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (2, 'Helen', 'Lofstrom', 20, 100000);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (3, 'Akiko', 'Toyota', 20, 50000);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (4, 'Jackie', 'Stough', 20, 40000);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (5, 'Richard', 'Foote', 20, 70000);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (6, 'Joe', 'Johnson', 20, 30000);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (7, 'Clark', 'Urling', 20, 90000);

CREATE TABLE bonuses (
employee_id NUMBER, bonus NUMBER DEFAULT 100);

INSERT INTO bonuses (employee_id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO bonuses (employee_id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO bonuses (employee_id) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO bonuses (employee_id) VALUES (6);
INSERT INTO bonuses (employee_id) VALUES (7);
COMMIT;
```

Now we have a sample data structure lets do some merging:

```
MERGE INTO bonuses b
USING (
  SELECT employee_id, salary, dept_no
  FROM employee
  WHERE dept_no =20) e
ON (b.employee_id = e.employee_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET b.bonus = e.salary * 0.1
  DELETE WHERE (e.salary < 40000)
;
```

So this command the [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/img/merge.gif) syntax using the [merge_update_clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm#i2081030):
`MERGE INTO` (table/view)
`USING` (table/view)
`ON` (condition)
`WHEN MATCHED THEN`
`UPDATE SET` (column..expression)
`DELETE WHERE` (condition)

I guess what I'm hinting at is that you are missing your `UPDATE SET` clause as well as the `DELETE` conditions. I recommend following up on the `MERGE` syntax.
**Edit:**SQLFiddle is back [so here you go](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/340e0/16/1).

Comment: If I dont need any UPDATE, then how does this would work? Can you please help